# Index out of range python stock analysis

Tags: python, model, stock

I'm making a stock prices predict model, I got a 1 year historical prices as a "database". As I runned the code I got a list index out of range, tried using a row and column selection but it didn't work

```
def get_data(IndFut):
with open('IndFut.csv','r') as csvfile:
    csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(csvFileReader)
    for row in csvFileReader:
        dates.append(int(row[0].split('/')[0]))
        prices.append(float(row[1]))
```

Here is the data

```
    Day        Close    Open    High     Low   Volume
11/01/2018  79830   78590   79845   78555   
10/01/2018  78638   78850   79025   78510   57030
09/01/2018  79242   79750   79925   79100   67500
08/01/2018  79829   79730   79915   79055   57270
```

And the following error appears:

```
prices.append(float(row[1]))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

How do I procced?

Comment: What have you checked? Try printing variable `row` and see why `row[1]` fails.

Comment: Simply print(row[1])?

Comment: Appending to Sam's comment, you cant be certain that your file has two columns. In the case in which the file has a single column, row[0] will be fine but row[1] will fail. Place here a sample of the data that is failing (even if you change the values for security) and you will get more help.

Comment: @LucasSaladini No, print(row).

Comment: @LucasSaladini; Should probably edit the question and put the data there. Nonetheless - it looks like your data is not comma delimited (which may be the default for the csv reader.) You may need to tell it to use a space as a delimiter. Showing the results of print(row) will help.

Comment: It's a CSV file.
When I tried to print row it says that "name row is not defined"

Comment: @LucasSaladini; put your print(row) inside the for-loop and, for troubleshooting, comment out the other code inside the loop. Once we see that output, we can get you an answer pretty easily I think.

Comment: For now, try changing your reader to; csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t'). I think your csv is tab delimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to split each row to eliminate the semicolons.

```
rows = [['11/01/2018;79830;78590;79845;78555;;']]

dates = []
prices = []

for row in rows:
    row = ''.join(rows[0]).split(';')
    dates.append(int(row[0].split('/')[0]))
    prices.append(float(row[1]))    

print(dates)
# [11]    

print(prices)
# [79830.0]
```

Rewriting the function:

```
def get_data(IndFut):
    with open(IndFut,'r') as csvfile:
        csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)

        next(csvFileReader)

        for row in csvFileReader:
            row = ''.join(rows[0]).split(';')
            dates.append(int(row[0].split('/')[0]))
            prices.append(float(row[1]))
```

Comment: I tried your code and gived me this

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Each row is a `list`. Please see the changes.

Comment: It worked! But how do I use it in the entire csv file?

Comment: Try changing `rows` in my `for` loop to `csvFileReader`.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so so much srig!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Please mark the best answer as accepted. I didn't know they're semicolon delimited.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your data is tab delimited, so you need to indicate as such, and you may need to remove spaces.

```
def get_data(IndFut):
with open('IndFut.csv','r') as csvfile:
    csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    next(csvFileReader)
    for row in csvFileReader:
        try:
            dates.append(int(row[0].split('/')[0]))
            prices.append(float(row[1]))
        except:
            print(f"failed to process row {row}")
```

[Edit] Not sure I understand why...but try this;

```
def get_data(IndFut):
with open('IndFut.csv','r') as csvfile:
    csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    next(csvFileReader)
    for row in csvFileReader:
        split_row = row[0].split(';')[:-1]
        try:
            dates.append(int(split_row[0].split('/')[0]))
            prices.append(float(split_row[1]))
        except:
            print(f"failed to process row {split_row}")
```

Comment: It gives me a atribute error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'trim'

Comment: Well, it failed to process all rows

Comment: Any rows or all rows? show the printout of the rows that failed please.

Comment: failed to process row ['11/01/2018;79830;78590;79845;78555;;']
failed to process row ['10/01/2018;78638;78850;79025;78510;57030;']
failed to process row ['09/01/2018;79242;79750;79925;79100;67500;']
failed to process row ['08/01/2018;79829;79730;79915;79055;57270;']
And it goes